# In-place sort_values in pandas what does it exactly mean?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, in-place

Maybe a very naive question, but I am stuck in this: `pandas.Series` has a method `sort_values` and there is an option to do it "in place" or not. I have Googled for it a while, but I am not very clear about it. It seems that this thing is assumed to be perfectly known to everybody but me. Could anyone give me some illustrative explanation how these two options differ each other for dummies...?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: The `inplace` parameter is a more generic term w.r.t pandas and not specific to sort_values alone. You can see it in several functions like pd.fillna, pd.replace etc. Whenever the `inplace` is set to True, it modifies the existing data frame and you need not assign it to a new data frame.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here an example. `df1` will hold sorted dataframe and `df` will be intact

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[22,22,3],
                  index=[dt(2016, 11, 10, 0), dt(2016, 11, 10, 13), dt(2016, 11, 13, 5)],
                  columns=['foo'])

df1 = df.sort_values(by='foo')
print(df, df1)
```

In the case below, `df` will hold sorted values

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[22,22,3],
                  index=[dt(2016, 11, 10, 0), dt(2016, 11, 10, 13), dt(2016, 11, 13, 5)],
                  columns=['foo'])

df.sort_values(by='foo', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 8):

As you can read from the [sort_values document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values), the return value of the function is a series. However, it is a new series instead of the original.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print(s)
a   -0.872271
b    0.294317
c   -0.017433
d   -1.375316
e    0.993197
dtype: float64

s_sorted = s.sort_values()

print(s_sorted)

d   -1.375316
a   -0.872271
c   -0.017433
b    0.294317
e    0.993197
dtype: float64

print(id(s_sorted))
127952880

print(id(s))
127724792
```

So `s` and `s_sorted` are different series. 
But if you use inplace=True.

```
s.sort_values(inplace=True)
print(s)
d   -1.375316
a   -0.872271
c   -0.017433
b    0.294317
e    0.993197
dtype: float64

print(id(s))
127724792
```

It shows they are the same series, and no new series will return.

Comment: Not OP but thanks a lot for your answer. Is it similar as the idea of View and Copy or am I confusing two completely different problems? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu I am not sure what you mean by View and Copy.  From my understanding, `inplace` means the existing data is modified, and without `inplace`, the existing data is copied to another place and some action is performed on the new data. So the existing data is preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is all I need to understand the concept and the process!

Answer (score 2):

`inplace = True` changes the actual list itself while sorting.
`inplace = False` will return a new sorted list without changing the original.
By default, `inplace` is set to `False` if unspecified.